# Oracle Sql query for Timezone conversion of multiple datetimes

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to convert the timezone of a column having data like:

"18-May-2018 01:37 PM - its done for example one. 19-Jun-2018 07:44 AM - its done for example two. 27-Jul-2018 - no other thing is left."

All these datetime are in GMT and I want to change these to EST.

Please help me out to get the solution.

Comment: Why tag `MS SQL Server` when your question is for `Oracle` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
SELECT 
    FROM_TZ({your_column}, 'UTC') AT TIME ZONE 'EST'
FROM dual;
```